# How to host React.js Web Application on IIS or Window Server?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, web-deployment

I'm new to deploy React.js Web Application on Window Server. How can I host react.js web application on IIS?

Your advise is most welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure how you are compiling your code, but in general there should be a public folder somewhere in your solution, so the static files are there, just set this public folder on IIS to serve static file on a route you like.

Of course, this solves how to serve the html/css and react complied scripts, but you need to go a little further to have access to the api used by react on browser side, and it depends on what framework you've used for that.

Comment: I usually compile with the command "yarn start" since I started my project with create-react-app and my api project was developed using ASP.Net Core 2.0. So, you means I only need to have the public folder of my project under IIS's webroot directory? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I do, but I've never used yarn, so not sure how it works, there should be somewhere in you project path a folder to static files with html, css and the bundle js with your react application
There are on yarn docs a "yarn run build" with calls babel to generate the static files, and I think babel will need its own config json file as well
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/

Comment: Ok, I will try that way again and will reply to you here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did tons of research on this topic and I found out that I had to piece together the information. This blog along with several others got me where I needed to host a react application on Windows Server 2008. First, I created an AMI in AWS using Windows 2008 Service Pack 2, this video by Brett Beck [How To Setup Windows Server With Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FepK5pV39c). Then I needed to research installing node.js on Windows Server 8, I found this article to be extremely helpful. [Admin Ahead Blog by CHETAN SINGH](https://admin-ahead.com/blog/node-js-installation-windows-2008-r2-server/). Then installing IIS correctly on Windows 8: [Installing IIS Correctly on Windows Server R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2).

I was able to deploy my react boiler plate by pointing my default document to the ./dist folder with index.html being the primary file.